# Python's os.listdir behaviour on Windows

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, filepath

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir('c:/python27')
>>> os.listdir('c:')
['Tools', 'include', 'python.exe', 'libs', 'DLLs', 'Lib', 'NEWS.txt',
'w9xpopen.exe', 'Doc', 'pythonw.exe', 'LICENSE.txt', 'README.txt', 'tcl']
>>> os.listdir('c:/')
['users', 'Program Files', 'Python27', 'windows']
```

Why is the "/" after "c:" affecting the outcome? Is there a way to get `os.listdir('c:')` to return the contents of "c:/"?

Comment: Welcome to Windows.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is not specific to Python, it's a Windows question at heart.

In Windows `C:` and `C:\` (or, alternatively `C:/`) have quite different meanings:

- `C:` refers to the current directory on the drive `C:`
- `C:\` (and `C:/`) refers to the root directory of the drive `C:`

While UNIX-like operating systems simply have a "current directory", Windows has two separate notions:

- the current drive and
- the current directory *per drive*

So the current drive could be `D:`, the current directory on `C:` could be `\Windows` (effectively `C:\Windows`) and the current directory on `D:` could be `\Data` (effectively `D:\Data`). In this scenario resolution would work like this:

- `.` would refer to `D:\Data`
- `\` would refer to `D:\`
- `C:` would refer to `C:\Windows`
- `C:\Foo` would refer to `C:\Foo`

So if you want to have information about a *specific* directory, you should always use a *full* path *including* both a drive and a directory, such as `C:\`.

Answer (score 4):

C: uses the current working directory on the C: drive.

C:/ is translated to C:\ and uses the root directory on the C: drive.

> Is there a way to get os.listdir('c:') to return the contents of "c:/"?

No.

You can, however, change directories.  But that may be confusing to users.