# Python error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python

Im trying to run my code with this but keep running into a file not found error.

```
files = [i for i in os.listdir('C:/Users/me/Desktop/python data')]
for filename in files:    
    data = pandas.read_excel(str(filename))
```

I've tried looking around but cant seem to understand.

Running `print(os.getcwd())` does find the file in the folder but i still get the error message

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python's os.listdir behaviour on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258993/pythons-os-listdir-behaviour-on-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the path and the filename returned from `os.listdir`:

```
PATH = 'C:/Users/me/Desktop/python data'
files = [os.path.join(PATH, i) for i in os.listdir(PATH)]
for filename in files:
    data = pandas.read_excel(str(filename))
```

Further recommendations:

1. You can use `pathlib`'s `.glob` to get the full path without using `os.path.join`.
2. Also, if you use `read_excel`, please consider filtering by xls/xlsx files:

Code example:

```
import pathlib


path = pathlib.Path('C:/Users/me/Desktop/python data')
excel_filter = "*.xls*"
for filename in path.glob(excel_filter):
    print(filename)
```